# Почему я не получил знак популярный вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, знаки, золотые-знаки

У меня есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449808/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0). У него 10k просмотров. Почему мне не дали знак "популярный вопрос"?

Comment: и отличная реклама, сейчас как раз наберёте 10к

Comment: Поздравляем https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=188116

Comment: Еее.. первая голда. Спасибо

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Потому что ещё нет - дурацкое округление:

[image: 9941]